# Dojo related Error: declare: mixin #0 is not a callable constructor

Tags: javascript, dojo

In our project we are using Dojo and JavaScript. We are getting following error

`Error: declare: mixin #0 is not a callable constructor.`

Codes we have written are following-

```
[ require({
    packages : [ {
        name : "dojoWidget",
        location : "/wle/js/DojoWidgets"
    } ]
}, [ "dojox/widget/Standby", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/_base/array", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dojoWidget/SolutionEditor/partitionContentPane", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
     "dojoWidget/SolutionEditor/wleDefinitionTree", "dojoWidget/SolutionEditor/SolutionEditorConstants" ,
     "dojoWidget/OneTimeHelp/OneTimeHelp",     
     "dijit/Menu", "dijit/MenuItem",
        "dojo/domReady!" ], function(Standby, Button, array, BorderContainer, partitionContentPane, ContentPane, 
                dT, solutionEditorConstants, OneTimeHelp, Menu, MenuItem) {

    wleDefinitionTreeSizedFlag = false;
    SEConstants = new solutionEditorConstants();
    isSized = function(xml){
        for (var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++){
            if (xml.childNodes[i].tagName == "Tier"){
                for (var j = 0; j <xml.childNodes[i].childNodes.length; j++){
                    if (xml.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].tagName == "System"){
                        for (var k = 0; k <xml.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].childNodes.length; k++){
                            if (xml.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].childNodes[k].tagName == "ImmediateSelection" ||
                                    xml.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].childNodes[k].tagName == "GrowtheSelection"){
                                    return true;
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    require([ "dojo/ready", "dojox/xml/parser" ], function(ready, parser) {
        ready(function() {
            var isPrune = getCookie("isPrune");             
            var mem=getCookie("modifiedMemoryObj");
            document.cookie = "isPrune=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC"; 
            document.cookie = "modifiedMemoryObj=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC"; 
            loadTreeFromRest(contextRoot + "rest/sizing?sessionID=" + document.getElementById('sessionID').value+"&isPrune="+isPrune+"&useMemory="+mem);
        });
    }); ]
```

Can anyone tell why am getting this error..Previously it was working fine.
Thanks

Comment: could give more info about error , check in console and post the whole error tree !

Comment: Followings are error tree  : - "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://www.project.com/webmaster/dbip/ip/?callback=dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript1._jsonpCallback"
?callba...allback
Error: declare: mixin #0 is not a callable constructor.

Comment: so seems dojo cant find your Dojowidgets package , try to add the 
 `packages : [ {
        name : "dojoWidget",
        location : location.pathname.replace(/[^\/]+$/, '')+"wle/js/DojoWidgets"
    } ]`

Comment: @bRIMO :- NO, I am getting the same error.

Comment: where the `wle/js/DojoWidgets` is located in your project ? could you give screen shot od your tree project

Comment: DojoWidgets is located under WebContent foder. WebContent->js->DojoWidgets

Comment: ???? so whats the wle folder here ?  try to access from browser 
localhost:port/wle/js/DojoWidgets/SolutionEditor/SolutionEditorConstants.js

Comment: The full folder structure is like WLE->WebContent->js->DojoWidgets

Comment: i only solution is to try acces the folder from url localhost:port/wle/js/DojoWidgets/SolutionEditor/SolutionEdi‌​torConstants.js until it gona give you the file content

Comment: bRIMO ..Seems we have resolved the issue. Thanks for the help

Comment: great , what was the issue ?

Comment: It was related to Dojo version..I have changed the version and now its up and running :-)